# How to use protocol buffer FieldMask in Go

Tags: python, go, protocol-buffers, api-design, grpc-go

[Python Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated) lists [Well Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#wkt), but there is no equivalent in [Go Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated). I assume if there was, it would document this package [google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known).

Specifically, I was looking for documentation on `FieldMask`. While it's completely absent on [Go Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated), I did find it on [go.dev](https://go.dev) (https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/fieldmaskpb).

**Question**

The Python implementation of [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#fieldmask) provides a `MergeMessage` function that merges fields specified in `FieldMask` from source to destination. This is really useful in [API update](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods#update) operations because you can easily merge 2 proto messages while honoring the `FieldMask`:

```py
# get field mask and message from request
updated_message = request.message
field_mask      = request.mask

# load original message from database 
original_message = read_from_db(request.id)

# source, destination
field_mask.MergeMessage(updated_message, original_message)

# original_message is now updated according to the field mask
```

Is there an equivalent convenience function in Go? If not, how should proto messages be merged using a `FieldMask`? Is there a reference implementation or example I could follow? I couldn't find any use of `FieldMask` in [grpc-go/examples/](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples).

While there is a proto [Merge function](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.25.0/proto#Merge), it merges all fields and there is no way to incorporate a `FieldMask` to merge only specific fields.

Answer (score 4):

`fieldmaskpb.FieldMask` type provides someuseful methods like `IsValid` and `Normalize`.

The [append](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/fieldmaskpb@v1.27.1#FieldMask.Append) method looks like can be used in your case of merging.

There are some great repo to deal with field mask, [fieldmask-utils](https://github.com/mennanov/fieldmask-utils), and [fmutils](https://github.com/mennanov/fmutils).

Based on my understanding, after you get the `FieldMask` value, which is a `[]string`:

1. with go's v1 api, you need to use `reflect` on the `struct`(which converted from pb message) or use a `map[string]interface{}`(converted from pb message) to deal with the `FieldMask`
2. or with go's v2 api, it becomes easier, as for the reflect api on `proto.Message`. Check the [code](https://github.com/mennanov/fmutils/blob/9e8bf86b10b99108971344c2fe763bfa20536bb8/fmutils.go#L67)

You can go for more code details in the above repo to help you write your own code related to `FieldMask`.